# ColorFunction scaling based on third column in matrix

Tags: plotting, color

I would like to plot data so that the first column is in the x axis, the second column is in the y axis and the third column is the input for a custom ColorFunction. The ColorFunction is simple: white if the third column is 0 and increasingly darker shades of gray as values in the third column increase.

Part of my problem is that the data I am working with is not symmetric so I am having problems calling it.

Here is a MWE

```
list = {{{1, 1.5, 10}}, {{2, 1.5, 11}, {2, 1.4, 0}}, {{3, 1.5, 0}, {3,
     1.4, 0}, {3, 1.6, 11}}, {{4, 1.5, 0}, {4, 1.4, 0}, {4, 1.6, 
    13}, {4, 1.55, 0}}, {{5, 1.5, 0}, {5, 1.4, 0}, {5, 1.6, 0}, {5, 
    1.55, 0}, {5, 1.65, 13}}}

ListPlot[Flatten[list, 1][[All, {1, 2}]], 
 ColorFunction -> 
  If[Flatten[list, 1][[All, {3}]] > 0, ColorData["GrayTones"], 
   White], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

I'm sure this will be quite simple for someone on here. Any suggestions are much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list0 = {{{1, 1.5, 10}}, {{2, 1.5, 11}, {2, 1.4, 0}}, {{3, 1.5, 
     0}, {3, 1.4, 0}, {3, 1.6, 11}}, {{4, 1.5, 0}, {4, 1.4, 0}, {4, 
     1.6, 13}, {4, 1.55, 0}}, {{5, 1.5, 0}, {5, 1.4, 0}, {5, 1.6, 
     0}, {5, 1.55, 0}, {5, 1.65, 13}}};

list = Flatten[list0, 1]
listNonZero = Cases[list, {_, _, Except[0 | 0.]}]
```

Remove unwanted points completely from the plot ...

```
ListPlot[Thread[{listNonZero[[All, {1, 2}]]}], 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Evaluate[ColorData["GrayTones"][1 - #] & /@ 
    Rescale[listNonZero[[All, 3]]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

... or keep them in the plot and paint them white.

```
ListPlot[Thread[{list[[All, {1, 2}]]}], 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Evaluate[If[# > 0, ColorData["GrayTones"][1 - #], White] & /@ 
    Rescale[list[[All, 3]], MinMax[listNonZero[[All, 3]]]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, this is very close. What I want is for points with 0 in the third column to be white and for points with nonzero third columns to be scaled so that higher values in the third column correspond to darker shades of gray

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was changing the code and then forgot about your non-zero condition. I have fixed my answer.